Polly Resilience context is empty
I'm implementing resilience for my .NET Core Web Api, and I need a way to pass a value using the ResilienceContext, but when I'm debugging, the args.Context.Properties is always empty. I don't know what I'm missing.
I'm using Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Resilience that uses Polly
Here's the code the I have:
public static class ResilienceKeys
{
    public static readonly ResiliencePropertyKey<string> LocationId = new("location-id");
}

// WordPressService.cs

public class WordPressService : IWordPressService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly ResiliencePipelineProvider<string> _pipelineProvider;

    public WordPressService(HttpClient httpClient, ResiliencePipelineProvider<string> pipelineProvider)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.example.com/");

        _pipelineProvider = pipelineProvider;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetBannersByLocationAsync(int locationId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var pipeline = _pipelineProvider.GetPipeline<HttpResponseMessage>("my-pipeline");

        var context = ResilienceContextPool.Shared.Get(cancellationToken);

        context.Properties.Set(ResilienceKeys.LocationId, locationId.ToString());

        var response = await pipeline.ExecuteAsync<HttpResponseMessage, ResilienceContext>(
            async (context, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                // Simulate an error for testing purposes
                await Task.Delay(100, cancellationToken);
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                return response;
            },
            context,
            cancellationToken);

        ResilienceContextPool.Shared.Return(context);

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}


Also I'm using dependency injection to add the ResiliencePipeline, with a RetryStrategy and a FallbackStrategy to get content from a database in case of the WordPress server is not responding
// Program.cs

builder.Services.AddResiliencePipeline<string, HttpResponseMessage>("my-pipeline", (pipelineBuilder, context) =>
{
    var predicateBuilder = new PredicateBuilder<HttpResponseMessage>()
        .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
        .HandleResult(r => r.StatusCode >= HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);

    pipelineBuilder
    .AddFallback(new FallbackStrategyOptions<HttpResponseMessage>()
    {
        ShouldHandle = predicateBuilder,
        FallbackAction = async (args) =>
        {
            if (args.Context.Properties.TryGetValue(ResilienceKeys.LocationId, out var data))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FallbackAction, Location Id: {0}", data);
            }

            var fallbackResponse = new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Content = new StringContent("Fallback content")
            };

            return Outcome.FromResult(fallbackResponse);
        }
    })
    .AddRetry(new RetryStrategyOptions<HttpResponseMessage>()
    {
        ShouldHandle = predicateBuilder,
        Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
        MaxRetryAttempts = 2,
        BackoffType = DelayBackoffType.Exponential,
        UseJitter = true,
    });
});


The short answer is that you have used a wrong overload of ExecuteAsync. You should use this one:
var response = await pipeline.ExecuteAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(
    async ctx =>
    {
        // Simulate an error for testing purposes
        await Task.Delay(100, ctx.CancellationToken);
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    },
    context);


The overload, what you have used, is not taking advantage of the Context. If you see the method signature then it becomes clear.
public async ValueTask<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult, TState>(
    Func<TState, CancellationToken, ValueTask<TResult>> callback,
    TState state,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)

You have passed the Context as the state object. Here we have documented what is the difference between Context and State.
Currently there is no such overload which anticipates both a CancellationToken and a Context. But you don't even need one.
Whenever you request a Context from the ResilienceContextPool then the passed CancellationToken is attached to the retrieved Context. If you take a look at the suggested solution's code fragment then you can spot that the CancellationToken was accessed via the Context (ctx.CancellationToken).
So, you should use the following overload:
public async ValueTask<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(
    Func<ResilienceContext, ValueTask<TResult>> callback,
    ResilienceContext context)


As a side note please don't forget to return back the borrowed resilience context to the pool:
ResilienceContextPool.Shared.Return(context);


Thank you so much, I just apply the changes and it worked. Saved my day! I forgot to add the ResilienceContextPool.Shared.Return(context); on the question. I'm going to update it
